# What is the difference between @Bind and @BindBean in JDBI?

Tags: java, jdbi

What is the difference between `@Bind` and `@BindBean` in [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/five_minute_intro/)?

Example code:

```
@SqlUpdate("insert into myObject (id, name) values (:id, :name)")
int insert(@BindBean MyObject myObject);

@SqlQuery("select id, name from myObject where id = :id")
MyObject findById(@Bind("id") long id);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [JDBI docs](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_argument_binding/)

> The @Bind annotation binds a single named argument. If no value is specified for the annotation it will bind the argument to the name it.

and

> The @BindBean annotation binds JavaBeans™ properties by name. If no value is given to the annotation the bean properties will be bound directly to their property names. If a value is given, the properties will be prefixed by the value given and a period.